# get an HTMLElement using enzyme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

Here is the function that I want to test using jest and enzyme:

```js
const getTotalValue = (list: string[], element: HTMLElement) : number => list
  .map((prop: string) => element ? parseInt(Object(window.getComputedStyle(element))[prop], 10) : 0)
  .reduce((prev, cur) => prev + +cur, 0);
```

Here is how I am trying to test it:

```js
describe('getTotalValue', () => {
  it('returns a number', () => {
    const properties: string[] = [ 'height', 'width' ];
    const wrapper = mount(<div style={{ height: 500, width: 200 }}>test</div>);
    expect(getTotalValue(properties, wrapper.instance())).not.toBeNaN();
  });
});
```

When I do `wrapper.instance()`, The test is passing, but I am getting this error at compile time:

```
Argument of type 'Component<{}, {}, any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLElement'.
```

I know that this is a typescript error. But I want to know how can I get an HTMLElement using enzyme?